# Filter out docs from $lookup aggregation in a MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to get user reviews that depends on restaurant id, so I've used aggregation like so and it works fine if I change the match expression from this:

```
$match: {
    restaurant: { $ne: [], $eq: { isApproved: true } },
},
```

to this:

```
$match: {
  restaurant: { $ne: [] },
},
```

$ne is checking whether the restaurant field is not empty. And my problem is excatly here.

**I can't filter out reviews to restaurants if the restaurant is not approved(not the review)**.

What I've tried:

- To use pipeline in lookup.
- To use $cond expression under reviews.$map.in
- To use $filter expression under reviews.$map.input

Edit: Using a pipeline in lookup to subuery also not worked.

```
$lookup: {
   from: 'restaurants',
   localField: 'reviews._restaurantId',
   foreignField: '_id',
   pipeline: [{ $match: { isApproved: true } }]
   as: 'restaurant',
},
```

I also suspect it is not possible to achieve both filtering and grouping in a query together.

Here is the full query below:
Thanks for your help.

```
const users = await db
            .collection('users')
            .aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'restaurants',
                        localField: 'reviews._restaurantId',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'restaurant',
                    },
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        restaurant: { $ne: [], $eq: { isApproved: true } },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        name: 1,
                        surname: 1,
                        image: 1,
                        reviews: {
                            $map: {
                                input: '$reviews',
                                as: 'review',
                                in: {
                                    $mergeObjects: [
                                        '$$review',
                                        {
                                            $let: {
                                                vars: {
                                                    restaurantName: {
                                                        $arrayElemAt: [
                                                            '$restaurant.basics.name',
                                                            { $indexOfArray: ['$restaurant._id', '$$review._restaurantId'] },
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    restaurantCity: {
                                                        $arrayElemAt: [
                                                            '$restaurant.location.city',
                                                            { $indexOfArray: ['$restaurant._id', '$$review._restaurantId'] },
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    restaurantState: {
                                                        $arrayElemAt: [
                                                            '$restaurant.location.state',
                                                            { $indexOfArray: ['$restaurant._id', '$$review._restaurantId'] },
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    isApproved: {
                                                        $arrayElemAt: [
                                                            '$restaurant.isApproved',
                                                            { $indexOfArray: ['$restaurant._id', '$$review._restaurantId'] },
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                },
                                                in: {
                                                    restaurant: {
                                                        name: '$$restaurantName',
                                                        city: '$$restaurantCity',
                                                        state: '$$restaurantState',
                                                        isApproved: '$$isApproved',  // i actually do not need this info on frontend, just added this to see if if this property is properly set.
                                                    },
                                                },
                                            },
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                { $unwind: '$reviews' },
                { $sort: { 'reviews.date': -1 } },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: '$_id',
                        name: { $first: '$name' },
                        surname: { $first: '$surname' },
                        image: { $first: '$image' },
                        reviews: { $push: '$reviews' },
                    },
                },
                { $limit: 12 },
            ])
            .toArray();
```

Comment: Have you checked out [subquery](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection) in `$lookup`?

Comment: Thank you @ray, I've also tried the pipeline approach but no luck ./

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can post some sample documents and the expected output

Comment: The problem is here: `$match: {restaurant: { $ne: [], $eq: { isApproved: true } }}`. What do you want to achieve here?